# Get values from MVC3 model to pass Ajax and assign in array

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

How do I get values from model using Ajax and assign these values in an array on the client?

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Oku()
{
    var query = from table in db.news where table.image_name select table;
    return Json(query,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My Ajax script is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "Home/Oku",
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
        // Some codes to assign array
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data returned from action is already in array format, since the query result is an IEnumerable.

You need to implement success callback in the ajax.

```
$(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get", url: "Home/Oku", data: {}, dataType: "json", 
            success: function (data) {
               alert(data[0])
            }
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just implement a `success` callback in your Ajax call.  Also you don't need to specify `get`, it is the default behavior.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/Oku",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resp) {             
         // do something with resp object which is an array 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) instead of an ActionResult.

Here's a [Tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx)

Comment: Actually `ActionResult` is the base of `JsonResult`.  If you return `Json({..})` with an `ActionResult` it should still work.

Comment: Nice to know...I think I'd still use it for coding clarity.

Comment: Ya there is one situation where I find it useful to use the generic `ActionResult`.  If you have a method that may return either a `JsonResult` or possibly something else (`ViewResult`, `RedirectResult`, etc) in case of an error or some special case.